# Selecting options from hidden dropdownbox using jQuery and Selenium WebDriver using Python

Tags: jquery, python, selenium-webdriver

I want to select options from hidden dropdownbox but I am unable to do this.

The site which I want to automate is [www.geforce.com/drivers](http://www.geforce.com/drivers). In that page I want to automate '*manual driver search*'. I am trying to select options from first dropdownbox by using below code but I'm not able to do it.

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementBYID('manualsearch-0').style='display.block');
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('manualSearch-0)
for o in select.options:
select.select_by_visible_text(o.text)
```

Comment: Just FYI you have `'` as outer and inside of the string. You need to either use `"` inside or the other way around. You are also missing some closing parenthesis and apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually those hidden drop-downs are not useful for you.

`nvFrame-selectBox-dropdown` class will give you list of drop-downs available for manual search.

When you click on any dropdown, dropdown-options html becomes visible with class `selectBox-dropdown-menu`. You can check bottom part of HTML in console.
As these `options` are in `ul` and `li` tags, so you can't use `Select` method of selenium.

Now we need to find visible `ul` from all results.
 I have used 4th dropdown and selected 3rd option from bottom in this example.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".nvFrame-selectBox-dropdown")[3].click()
time.sleep(2)
uls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".selectBox-dropdown-menu")
for ul in uls:
    if ul.is_displayed():
        visible_ul = ul
        break
print visible_ul.text
visible_ul.find_elements_by_css_selector("li")[-3].click()
```

This will work perfect when you are selecting option visible to human eye, you might need to scroll drop-downs lists in some cases.

Comment: BUt i am not able to select the options by uisng this

Comment: HI Dhiraj,i trying to select the options from first dropdownbox.I am able to select upto 2 options,after that i am getting error like Elements not found in the cache-perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up.Can you provide me the solution for this?